# Different between two text file

Tags: shell, unix

assuming i have two text file

file 1

```
    hello i am John
    and i live in Cairo
```

file 2

```
    hello i am Jogn 
    and i love in Cairo
```

and i need to list the different for words only (not space or any thing else) between two text to get the result as file 3 which will contain both words in list like the follwing

```
    file1     file2
    John      Jogn
    live      love
```

how i could do that?

i have tried

```
    diff file1 file2
```

but it does not help to get the result as desired

Thanks

Comment: You will have to write a shell script, if formatting is important.

Comment: What is the 'result as desired'?

Comment: try `diff --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side ` , it gives output almost in your desired format, you can add the filenames later also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '
    # BEGIN: print 1th & 2th args
    BEGIN{print ARGV[1], ARGV[2]}
    # if the current line is from "file1",
    # put line in the array "a" with the line number for key
    FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0}
    if current line is from "file2"
    FNR!=NR{
        # iterate over words of the current line
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            # split a[key current line] array in array "arr"
            split(a[FNR], arr)
            # test if both file1 and file2 Nth element match
            if (arr[i] != $i) {
                print arr[i], $i
             }
          }
     }
' file1 file2
```

Output :

```
/tmp/l1 /tmp/l2
John Jogn
live love
```

Comment: can you explicate that a little, please?

Comment: Post commented accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Use the `wdiff` command.

If you don't have it, it's in the "wdiff" package, which should be available in your system's repositories.

```
$ wdiff file1 file2
hello i am [-John-] {+Jogn+} 
and i [-live-] {+love+} in Cairo
```

If you want a graphical display, the `meld` program does a pretty good job (install the "meld" package if you don't already have it).

If you need a specific output format, you'll need to write a script. A good start is probably to filter each input file to put each word on a single line (`fmt -w 1` is a first approximation) and then diff the results.

Comment: it worked but how i can list the result in two column as in question?